# Android Bottom Sheet Is not Reacting To Touches and doesn't Scroll

Tags: android, android-layout, bottom-sheet

so I have a problem: I added a `LinearLayout` with layout_behaviour as `BottomSheetBehavior` to a `FrameLayout` view I created and added above one my `Activities`, but my bottom sheet is not scrollable, I can only change its state programatically but touches don't react. What do you think can be the problem?

This is my xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/rich_media_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

. . . . . . 

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/cue_point_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/cue_points_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

    . . . . . . 

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you share some code?

Comment: You need to use coordinator layout as parent of bottom sheet, and we need your code

Answer (score 0):

Use `CoordinatorLayout` as parent layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

bottom_sheet -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/bottom_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="204dp"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    .......

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use CoordinatorLayout as root layout

activity_main--

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f7f7f7">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <!-- Adding bottom sheet after main content -->
    <include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

bottom_sheet--

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_margin"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="56dp"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_margin"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="Order Details"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:text="₹475.00"></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Chicken Fried Rice 1x1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Chiken Tikka 1x2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_margin"
        android:text="Delivery Address"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Rohini delhi-42" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="#000"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:text="PROCEED PAYMENT"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

</LinearLayout>
```